# unifiedNativeAd's call-to-action button not working inside of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob, native-ads, unifiednativeadview

I am showing a set of unifiedNativeAds in a RecyclerView. Actually, I have no problem with this. I mean, everything works fine, except for the call-to-action button. If I click on it nothing happens.

I am storing the set of unifiedNativeAds inside dataSet (there is no problem with getting this set). Then I pass each unifiedNativeAd to the TemplateView provided by Google in the onBindViewHolder method (from my RecyclerView Adapter):

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder vholder, int i) {
    int type = getItemViewType(i);
    final UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder unifiedNativeAdViewHolder;
    UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd = (UnifiedNativeAd)dataSet.get(i);
    unifiedNativeAdViewHolder = (UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder)vholder;
    NativeTemplateStyle styles = new NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().build();
    unifiedNativeAdViewHolder.templateView.setStyles(styles);
    unifiedNativeAdViewHolder.templateView.setNativeAd(unifiedNativeAd);
}
```

and this is my UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder:

```
public class UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private UnifiedNativeAdView adView;
    TemplateView templateView;
    public UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
        super(view);
        adView = view.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_view);
        adView.setHeadlineView(adView.findViewById(R.id.primary));
        adView.setBodyView(adView.findViewById(R.id.secondary));
        adView.setCallToActionView(adView.findViewById(R.id.cta));
        adView.setIconView(adView.findViewById(R.id.icon));
        adView.setStarRatingView(adView.findViewById(R.id.rating_bar));
        adView.setStoreView(adView.findViewById(R.id.tertiary));
        adView.setAdvertiserView(adView.findViewById(R.id.tertiary));
        templateView = view.findViewById(R.id.my_template);
    }
    public UnifiedNativeAdView getAdView(){
        return adView;
    }
}
```

As said before my code works, and all the unifiedNativeAds are shown in the RecyclerView. However, the only thing that does not work is the call-to-action button. If I click on it nothing happens.

I have tried basically the same code outside of a RecyclerView and it works just fine.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thank you.

----  EXTRA INFO -----

If I use gnt_medium_template_view everything works great. But, with gnt_small_template_view it does not. So, the problem seems to be related to template itself.

Comment: found any solutions for this problem? i do have the same issue

Comment: Hello, @ngc4151. Sorry, I have not found a solution. Right now I am only using the gnt_medium_template (which works well).